# Sensitivity /Specificity versus cutoff point plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, statistics, classification

Is there a package for making a sensitivity/specificity versus cutoff point plot in R?
Preferable one that takes a glm object as an argument?

Something like this is what i am looking for:

[image]

PS: Does this plot have a name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead you can use a ROC curve to plot the sensitivity against 1-specificity.

```
library(Epi)
x <- rnorm( 100 )
z <- rnorm( 100 )
w <- rnorm( 100 )
tigol <- function( x ) 1 - ( 1 + exp( x ) )^(-1)
y <- rbinom( 100, 1, tigol( 0.3 + 3*x + 5*z + 7*w ) )
ROC( form = y ~ x + z , plot="sp" )
```

The `ROCR`  and `epicalc` packages produce similar plots. The [latter](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/epicalc/html/roc.html) should accept glm objects.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the ROC-curve is very useful, however i also need to the sensitivity/specificity curve :)

Comment: @Rasmus Use `plot="sp"` in this case.